# Implementation of Scrollbar in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

My problem is that my Maven-project (board game) take up quite a lot of size, and since my laptop is only 13 inches, I can not see the top and bottom part. I have tried many different lines of code that I found on the internet but it did not help. So my question is that; I have adjusted the size of my board game but I can only see that place inside the 400x400 dimension. So how can I add a scrollbar that can show the whole game by scrolling up and down, is it even possible?

I've tried to do something, it is commented out.

```
    Scene scene = this.stage.getScene();
    Parent root = scene.getRoot();
    ((BorderPane) root).setCenter(this.boardView);

    //ScrollPane sp = new ScrollPane();
    //sp.setContent(root);
    //Scene scene = this.stage.getScene(sp, 400, 400); //too many arguments..

    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.centerOnScreen();
    appController.startGame();
```

I know I have to put the 'sp' in the code below (that's also the solutions I've found on the internet):

```
Scene scene = new Scene(sp, 400, 400);
```

But, how would I be able to do it, when I am creating the object like this?

```
Scene scene = this.stage.getScene();
```

How would I add Scrollingbar in my Window?

Or is there a completely different way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A lot of the code you posted doesn't really make any sense. If you have

```
Scene scene = this.stage.getScene();
```

then obviously

```
stage.setScene(scene);
```

is completely pointless. Much of the rest of the code is not understandable either, at least without further context.

The basic answer to your question is that you wrap the `boardView` in a `ScrollPane`, and place the `ScrollPane` (instead of `boardView`) in the scene graph, wherever you need it. So something like

```
Scene scene = this.stage.getScene();
Parent root = scene.getRoot();
ScrollPane sp = new ScrollPane();
sp.setContent(this.boardView);
((BorderPane) root).setCenter(sp);
```